# Check/Uncheck Parent/Child Checkboxes using Jquery in MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, view, asp.net-mvc-5

I got confused on how to achieved what I have in my mind. I hope someone might give light on what I'm going to do. I have categories, primary and sub categories. Primary categories have multiple sub categories. I think my data pulling is not a problem, displaying the data is my problem. My data is like:

1. Foo (Primary)

   - Foo1 (Sub)
   - Foo2 (Sub)
2. Faa

   - Faa1
   - Faa2
   - Faa3
3. Fee

   - Fee1
   - Fee2
   - Fee3
4. Fuu

and so on.

My expected result will be like [this](http://jsfiddle.net/y9qj4gm5/7/)

So far, my code is

```
<div class="col-xs-4">
    @{
        foreach (var item in Model)
        {
            var isPrimary = item.IsPrimary ? "" : "col-xs-offset-1";
            var isHeader = item.IsPrimary ? "bolder" : "";
            <div class="checkbox checkbox-info @isPrimary">
                <input type="checkbox" id="@item.Key">
                <label for="@item.Key">
                    <span style="font-weight: @isHeader">@item.Name</span>
                </label>
            </div>
        }
    }
</div>
```

In my `Model` there is a tagging of boolean`IsPrimary` if the item is primary or not. I got confused in `<div class="col-xs-4">` part on how to loop for every primary with corresponding sub category.

Thanks for helping.

**UPDATE:**
It's now displaying accordingly using code below:

```
<form role="form">
    @for (var i = 0; i < Model.Count(); i++)
    {
        <div class="col-xs-4">
            <div class="checkbox checkbox-info">
                @Html.CheckBoxFor(m => m[i].IsSelected, new {id = Model[i].Key})
                <label for="@Model[i].Key"><b>@Model[i].Name</b></label>
            </div>
            @for (var g = 0; g < Model[i].SubsCategories.Count(); g++)
            {
                <div class="checkbox checkbox-info col-xs-offset-1">
                    @Html.CheckBoxFor(m => m[i].SubsCategories[g].IsSelected, new {id = Model[i].SubsCategories[g].Key})
                    <label for="@Model[i].SubsCategories[g].Key">@Model[i].SubsCategories[g].Name</label>
                </div>
            }
        </div>
    }
</form>
```

*Note:* By any chance you'll also encounter the problem of the checkbox is not working using the `awesome-bootstrap-checkbox`, because of the auto  generated hidden input field of CheckBoxFor. Just change the `tilde` `~` in css. From `checked + label:after` to `checked ~ label:after`

Comment: You should show your model. Your creating checkboxes with no relationship to your model so if your intending to submit a form, you current `foreach` wont work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all you may want to organize your Model in some structure that will be easy to use. For example:

```
public class Category
{
    public string Name {get; set;}
    public bool IsSelected {get; set;}
}

public class PrimaryCategory : Category
{        
    public IList<Category> SubCategories {get; set;}
}
```

Then in your view:

```
@model IList<PrimaryCategory>

@for(var i = 0; i < Model.Count(); i++)
{
   @Html.LabelFor(m=>m[i].IsSelected, Model[i].Name) 
   @Html.CheckBoxFor(m=>m[i].IsSelected , new{@class="checkbox checkbox-info"}) 
   @for(var j = 0; j < Model[i].SubCategories.Count(); j++)
   {
      @Html.LabelFor(m=>m[i].SubCategories[j].IsSelected, Model[i].SubCategories[j].Name) 
      @Html.CheckBoxFor(m=>m[i].SubCategories[j].IsSelected, new{@class="checkbox checkbox-info col-xs-offset-1"}) 
   }
}
```

Comment: Your properties are `string` - you cant use `CheckBoxFor()` on a `string` :)

Comment: The `Name` property is still a `string`

Comment: @StephenMuecke I see. Thanks, I'll try.

Comment: @AlexArt. Thanks too.

Comment: You will probably want to include an `ID` property (hidden input) so the item can be identified when posting, and the labels should be `@Html.LabelFor(m=>m[i].IsSelected, Model[i].Name) ` and `@Html.LabelFor(m=>m[i].SubCategories[j].IsSelected, Model[i].SubCategories[j].Name)`

Comment: @naru, It's Alex's answer :)

Comment: @StephenMuecke Oh, Sorry my bad, I thought it was you :D Well, thanks to both of you :)